# Debugging expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Using statements in code is quite easy to put breakpoints and debug:

```
bool GetBoolean()
{
    return true; // or false
}

int result;

if (GetBoolean())
    result = 1;
else
    result = 2;
```

a breakpoint can just be added to any line to see the results.

With expressions (conditional operator in particular) the code is much more readable, but debugging ease is lost:

```
bool GetBoolean() => true;

var result = GetBoolean() ? 1 : 2;
```

Is there a way to put a breakpoint only when 1 gets assigned?

A conditional breakpoint could be added to the line evaluating `GetBoolean()` but that will evaluate it twice which is not ideal.

Comment: you can use F11 instead of F10. Is this hel you ?

Comment: You could create a conditional break point after that line that only breaks if `result` is 1.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308469/how-to-set-conditional-breakpoints-in-visual-studio--net-or-in-visual

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN that works only in the first case, in the second case, it would only step into `GetBoolean()` but not step into the expression.

Comment: @juharr true, but imagine that instead of 1 and 2 you have another method call, in that case it won't stop in time (you will have to put two breakpoints in each of the methods instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: @DWorkAccount, Where did you add the breakpoint in first case? If you add it to line: if (GetBoolean()), it still hit the breakpoint twice. If you just want to debug the case 2 with value 1, I agree with juharr, we just could use the conditional breakpoint.

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT the breakpoint would be on the `result = 1` line, and if that is not an actual value, but another expression, then you will not be able to stop before evaluating it which could be a problem in some cases.

Comment: @DWorkAccount  Sorry it's really limited in VS, SO we could only place the breakpoint in the whole line of the expression. And 1)Press F11 while debugging to enter the line and see which function was hit; 2)Add a conditional breakpoint it will only break in the specified conditional;  To add a conditional breakpoint, first set the breakpoint, then right click the red dot -> "Condition..."

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT Unfortunately I know, I was hoping there was some trick to stop before assigning the result of the conditional expression regardless. In some cases it forces you to change the code for ease of debugging. I guess we should just discourage the use of methods in ?: expressions. Or give up and step into the method to find out if the one we are interested in is hit and step out if not.